# Overwrite existing map service in ArcGIS Server through ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server

I am using ArcGIS Desktop and Server 10.1. I want to over write existing map service though ArcPy and going through [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00540000001r000000) link  and getting an error`Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 22, in <module>
NameError: name 'draftPath' is not defined` and I am searching for this at my end.

I just want to know is there any alternative  to overwrite map service automatically after 1 hour in ArcGIS Server 10.1 ?

Comment: Going through following article but its for ArcGIS Online not for the ArcGIS Server (http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/04/23/updating-arcgis-com-hosted-feature-services-with-python/)

Comment: I guess this sample has something  wrong... you need to set sddraft folder path to draftpath variable.

Comment: @Darksanta thanks for reply so do you have the sample code?

Comment: I added in: #Delete old .sd
arcpy.Delete_management("YourName.sd")
print "YourName.sd deleted"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the sample code which customized from esri sample. This sample follows 3 steps,

1. Create SDDraft from mxd document
2. Set service type to esriServiceDefinitionType_Replacement of SDDraft
3. Stage and upload the sddraft with overwriting existed service.

```
import arcpy
import xml.dom.minidom as DOM

#define local variables
# wrkspc        mxd document directory
# mxdName       mxd document name
# con           ArcGIS Server Catalog path
# service       service name (include service direcotry)
# summary       service summary
# tags          services tags

wrkspc = 'C:/test/'
mxdName = 'sample.mxd'
con = 'GIS Servers/arcgis on localhost_6080 (admin)' 
service = 'MyMapService'
summary = 'Population Density by County'
tags = 'county, counties, population, density, census'

mapDoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(wrkspc + mxdName)
sddraft = wrkspc + service + '.sddraft'
sd = wrkspc + service + '.sd'

# create service definition draft
analysis = arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft(mapDoc, sddraft, service, 'ARCGIS_SERVER', 
                                          con, True, None, summary, tags)

# set service type to esriServiceDefinitionType_Replacement
newType = 'esriServiceDefinitionType_Replacement'
xml = sddraft
doc = DOM.parse(xml)
descriptions = doc.getElementsByTagName('Type')
for desc in descriptions:
    if desc.parentNode.tagName == 'SVCManifest':
        if desc.hasChildNodes():
            desc.firstChild.data = newType
outXml = xml    
f = open(outXml, 'w')     
doc.writexml( f )     
f.close()

# stage and upload the service if the sddraft analysis did not contain errors
if analysis['errors'] == {}:
    # Execute StageService
    arcpy.StageService_server(sddraft, sd)
    # Execute UploadServiceDefinition
    arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(sd, con)
else: 
    # if the sddraft analysis contained errors, display them
    print analysis['errors']
```

But make sure that if you are going to overwrite the service within directory such as "Maps/MyMapService", then you need to create "Maps" directory to mxd directory before run script.

Comment: thanks for this! Sorry for a Python newbie question: but while this code is working well for me if I overwrite a map service in the root directory, I am having trouble overwriting a map service in a sub folder. The comments in the code say to 'include service directory' in the service variable, but I am getting errors when I try this...in your comment you mention 'MXD directory' but OI am not sure how that relates to the service directory? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is SVCManifest? Is that the name of the summary?

Answer (score 6):

@JasonBK  @jasonbk

The CreateMapSDDraft method used in this sample asks for a {folder_name} parameter that was setted to None, so by default it points to root level (see below).
If you want to use a sub folder you must specify this instead of None, so in the sample you will use something like this:

```
analysis = arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft(mapDoc, sddraft, service, 'ARCGIS_SERVER', con, True, 'Maps', summary, tags)
```

To create (or overwrite) the service in the sub folder named Maps

`folder_name{String}`: a string that represents  a folder name to which you want to publish the service definition. If the folder does not currently exist, it will be created.  The default folder is the server root level.