# Overwrite existing Map Service through ArcPy keeping the existing cache tiling scheme

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server

This is a follow-up question to [Overwrite existing map service in ArcGIS Server 10.1 (through ArcPy)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61057/overwrite-existing-map-service-in-arcgis-server-10-1-through-arcpy)

The issue arises when I try to overwrite a map service that **has a cache already defined**.

If I overwrite the service through ArcGIS Desktop the existing cache tile scheme is recognized and preserved through the overwrite.
On the contrary, if I redeploy the service through Arcpy, that is create the .sddraft, transform it in .sd and upload it:

```
arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft(mapDoc, sddraft, service, 'ARCGIS_SERVER', 
                                      con, True, None, summary, tags)
arcpy.StageService_server(sddraft, sd)
arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(sd, con)
```

the existing tiling cache schema is not preserved and it's overwritten with the Bing standard cache tile scheme (I can see it in the generated .sddraft file).

Is there a way to preserve the existing schema?